# How do I enable browser caching that will never expire using Spring MVC WebContentInterceptor?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, browser-cache

We have setup a cacheMappings property to cache a static HTML file that never changes in our Spring MVC application.

```
<beans:bean id="webContentInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
<beansroperty name="cacheSeconds" value="0"/>
<beansroperty name="useExpiresHeader" value="true"/>
<beansroperty name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true"/>
<beansroperty name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="true"/>
<beansroperty name="cacheMappings">
    <beansrops>
        <beansrop key="/foo/**/*.html">31556926</beansrop>
    </beansrops>
</beansroperty>
```

Is there a better way to tell it to never expire the HTML files in this specific directory other than setting a really long cache period?

Answer (score 0):

WebCotextInterceptor maps these parameters directly to http headers which use time as the condition for expiring cached content.

Even more, spec. says 
"To mark a response as "never expires," an origin server sends an Expires date approximately one year from the time the response is sent. HTTP/1.1 servers SHOULD NOT send Expires dates more than one year in the future."

so cacheSeconds value should be approx. one year to follow the spec.

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.21

ps. looks like the code you pasted is broken or just contains typos.